# How to get list diff in Skylark?

Tags: bazel, skylark

I'd like to do something like:

```
    srcs = glob(["*.proto"]) - ["some.proto"],
```

That particular syntax isn't valid in Skylark. How do I go about accomplishing a list diff in Skylark?

Comment: Do you actually want to diff lists or to exclude that file from the glob? https://bazel.build/reference/be/functions#glob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glob` provides a `exclude` attribute, e.g.:

```
glob(
    [
        ".editorconfig",
        ".gitattributes",
        "third_party/eigen-*/**",
    ],
    exclude = ["devertexwahn/flatland/copy.bara.sky"],
),
```